# Scrapy providing unordered results

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm building a python scraper that for now, takes multiple URL's and extracts informations about car ads. The code looks like this:

```
import time
import csv
import scrapy
import json
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from urllib.parse import urlencode, quote
 


class autovitSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "autovit"
    start_urls = [
            url1,
            url2,
            url3,
            url4,
            url5,
        ]
        

    def parse(self, response):
        for list_ in response.css("div.offer-params"):
            for sublist in list_.css("ul.offer-params__list"):
                for elem in sublist.css("li.offer-params__item"):
                    if elem.css("span.offer-params__label::text").get() == "Anul" or elem.css("span.offer-params__label::text").get() == "Km" or elem.css("span.offer-params__label::text").get() == "Putere" or elem.css("span.offer-params__label::text").get() == "Capacitate cilindrica":
                        yield { 
                            "type":elem.css("span.offer-params__label::text").get(),
                            "value":elem.css("div.offer-params__value::text").get().replace("\n                ","").replace("         ","").replace("        ",""),
                        }
                    elif elem.css("span.offer-params__label::text").get() == "Marca" or elem.css("span.offer-params__label::text").get() == "Model" or elem.css("span.offer-params__label::text").get() == "Versiune" or elem.css("span.offer-params__label::text").get() == "Combustibil" or elem.css("span.offer-params__label::text").get() == "Culoare" or elem.css("span.offer-params__label::text").get() == "Cutie de viteze" or elem.css("span.offer-params__label::text").get() == "Numar de portiere":
                        yield { 
                            "type":elem.css("span.offer-params__label::text").get(),
                            "value":elem.css("a.offer-params__link::text").get().replace("\n                ","").replace("                ",""),
                        }
                    else:
                        pass

        yield {"url": response.request.url,
            "price": response.css("span.offer-price__number::text").get().replace("        ",""),
            
            }
```

I know the `yield`'s are ugly, but that's the site I'm scraping. Different attributes of a car have different html divs/a's/etc.

Anyway, I have noticed the following issue:

With multiple links, the spider **sometimes** (some runs return data in the right order, others not) starts messing up the order of the values it yields. I need that order in particular, and to have like, 10 lines for each ad scraped. Sometimes it scrambles together information from multiple ads. I am thinking that this is caused by asynchronous requests, as the spider loads multiple URL, starts scraping them at (almost) the same time, and yields information whenever it finds something of interest.
Now, I solved it by setting `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 1`, however this makes it (obviously) way slower. Is there any way to solve it without limiting the spider to only 1 request at the time? Something like yielding a separate `dict` for each URL it scrapes, or keeping track of the source of each element in the `dict`? I know I could get along it by creating an URL-based key for each entry in the dictionary, and then clumping together items with the same key. But again, this adds extra time associated with sorting and lowers efficiency.

Please keep in mind that I am not very educated on the technical side of how these things work. I understand conceptually how asynchronous requests, or `yield` command work, but I don't know the actual mechanism behind it. I don't even know how Scrapy itself works (creating all those files, handling them from the shell, etc) as I am used to coding single file programs that do what is inside them, without having a whole running procedure behind them. So an overly technical answer might be of no help.

For reference of my level of understanding, I tried creating a `for url in url_list:` loop outside of `class autovitSpider`, that iterates trough a list of url's and reruns the spider for each individual url. It didn't work, and yielded only the data for the first url. Also tried to loop inside `class autovitSpider` and give individual url's to `start_urls`. Same result as in the first case.

EDIT: When using multiple concurrent requests, there is also some sort of data loss:

`INFO: Stored json feed (41 items) in: a.json`

`INFO: Stored json feed (31 items) in: a.json`

Consecutive runs with no code changed.

Answer (score 0):

> Now, I solved it by setting CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 1

> I know I could get along it by creating an URL-based key for each entry in the dictionary, and then clumping together items with the same key. But again, this adds extra time associated with sorting and lowers efficiency.

Have you tried benchmarking this?

I think you must be losing a lot more process time by setting your concurrent requests to 1 than by sorting data in a dictionary. Setting your concurrent requests to 1 basically prevents you from benefitting from the effects of parallelization while adding all the problems related to parallelization. On the other hand dictionaries are that large in memory, unless you run on a toaster or you are scrapping something very huge you should be fine. Worst case scenario, you could dump your results in a database.

However since you are yielding asynchronous objects, if you do not match them on some kind of key, you won't be able to sort them properly. That is the nature of an asynchronous operations : you do not know when it will end.

So, **in short** : use a dict, you won't lose that much time or memory, but use more concurrent_requests.

> When using multiple concurrent requests, there is also some sort of data loss

Most servers have protections against numerous async requests.

I don't know much about your problem since I'm missing information such as your user-agent or the system you are scrapping but scrapy's doc says "Scrapy/VERSION (+https://scrapy.org)" is the default user-agent hence the server will recognize you as a bot and probably throttles requests at some point.

If your requests end up failing (because you are being throttled) then you probably won't have all the results. I see no try-except in your function, so basically if you fail you should receive an error but since your operations are all parallels it'll keep doing the other operations.

Let's say you have operation A-B-C, A=success=yields your stuff, B=failed=didn't yield, C=success=yields again. So if you are being throttle the first time everything was a success hence json has 3 entries, next time you had an error (because the server throttled you) hence json has 2 entries.

You should try artificially slowing you requests a bit to fit the requirements of the server. If the site you are looking at as documentation use it to throttle yourself. Otherwise it's trial and error.

I hope this'll help.

Comment: Great, thanks for the answer. I am using a custom user agent to make it look normal, as when using Scrapy's built in agent the site was blocking access. I guess I have to trial and error till I find the sweet spot no of concurrent requests bcs the data loss is substantial.